# Compare multiple columns as pair-wise for Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Excel/Google Sheets. I have a difficulty of writing a formula to compare columns as a pair-wise since the formula would be
so big as the day goes.

For example, there're 2 main columns `Foo` and `Bar`. I want to find the total number of days that `Foo`
and `Bar` are equal so the current formula is `=IF(A3 = G3, 1, 0)+IF(B3 = H3, 1, 0)+IF(C3 = I3, 1, 0)+...`

But this is kind of tedious because there're ~40 days to compare with. Are there any other alternatives
to write a formula in efficient way? Either `Google-App-Scripts` or `Excel Formula` is appreciated.

Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on below `google-sheet` formula. Adjust ranges as you need.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(A3:E3=G3:K3,1,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're needing to get such a total for each row and not merely a single row, try this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,MMULT(IF(A3:F=G3:L,1,0),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:F),1,1,0))))`

Of course you will need to adjust the three ranges to match your own FOO and BAR ranges.

This one formula will produce all results for all rows.

The `MMULT` function is tricky to explain to those as yet unfamiliar with it. But it's a powerful tool. I'll add a picture I created that may best explain what it does:

[image]

By making the second matrix a simple `SEQUENCE` of 1s as long as the other matrix is wide, we wind up multiplying everything by 1 before adding together. And since anything multiplied by 1 is itself, this combination serves only to do a row-by-row add.

Things to keep in mind with `MMULT`:

1.) *Every* cell in every matrix must be a number or it will produce an error.

2.) As in the above formula, there are ways to use either/or conditions to turn every cell in a matrix into a number.